# How can I erase the current line printed on console in C from the end?

Tags: c

I need to erase a printed character in a new line from the end.
That is if the statement is `printf("C++")`
I need to erase those 2 "++" printed and get the output "C".

```
    printf("hello");   printf("\rbye");
```

Using the above escape sequence '\r', replaces it only from the printed line beginning to get the output 'byelo', how to do it from the end to get 'hebye'?

Comment: ***[ncurses](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=ncurses+tutorial)*** is a library that provides extensive cursor control useful for console applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the backspace ASCII character:

```
printf("hello");
printf("\b");
```

Result:

```
hell
```

UPD: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12765325/288456)

Comment: It actually is implementation specific. The standard does not guarantee this behaviour (try this when redirecting the text to a printer).