# Replace Line in console c++

Tags: c++, windows, console

so no code to go off, but how would you replace a line in a console application in cpp. so instead of making a new line, you replace the text without creating a new line.
string toggle = "OFF";

```
printf("TOGGLE: %s", toggle);//an if statement changes toggle but never changes.
```

should i be looping?

example:

```
Toggle: ON //Instead of making a new line saying...
Toggle: OFF // how could i replace the Toggle: ON to say toggle off when i toggle off.
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you can control your terminal. There is a special character that might allow you to emulate a backspace ([`\b'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765297/erasing-using-backspace-control-character)) as you would have typed in the console. You can use that to control output within the same line.

In general for portable terminal control consider using [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or such.